# Does there exist a continuous surjection $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R\times[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions

Study if there is a continous and surjective function, $f: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}\times [0, 1]$ both with usual topolgy at $\mathbb{R}$ and at $\mathbb{R}\times [0,1]$, as i mentioned before i couldn't find a counter example and a surjective function neither, i will really appreciate any kind of help, thank you.

Comment: Have you heard of Peano curves?

Comment: As someone has already remarked (Peano curves), see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve

Comment: Or Cantor’s function can help too.

Comment: Yes i have heard about it, in fact i'm just studying, but i haven't get that topic totally, thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) is a continuous function from a Cantor set $C$ onto $[0,1]$.

As $C \times C \simeq C$ we in fact have a continuous function from $C$ onto $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ as well.

Take such a function $f_n, n \in \Bbb Z$ for a homeomorphic copy $C_n$ of $C$ in $[n,n+1]$ onto $[n,n+1] \times [0,1]$.

Now union up all such functions and extend linearly (or by Tietze) to get a continuous onto map from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R \times [0,1]$.